# Como pausar y reanudar un setInterval en este ejemplo?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

mi pregunta aqui es como pausar y reanudar en intervalo con un solo boton. Mi pause function lo muestra pero no funciona, quiero poner false para luego pasarlo a true y cuando ya es true volver a activar el intervalo, queria hacer algo parecido a lo que esta comentado mas abajo, pero no me va. Gracias

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Objeto Window</title>
 <meta charset="UTF8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="clearInterval.css">
 <body>
  <div class="bigBox">
   <!-- <button onclick="start()" id="start"type="button" name="button">START</button> -->
   <button onclick="desactivar()" id="desactivar"type="button" name="button">DESACTIVAR</button>
   <button onclick="ReStartFunction()" id="restart"type="button" name="button">RESTART</button>
   <button onclick="pause()"id="pause"type="button" name="button">PAUSAR</button>
   <button onclick="stop()"id="stop"type="button" name="button">STOP</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="result"></div></div>
  
  <script>
  
  let count = 0;
  let counter = setInterval(timer, 500)
  
  function timer(){
   count++;
   result.innerHTML = count;
  }
  
  function desactivar(){
   clearInterval(counter)
  }
  
  function ReStartFunction(){
   clearInterval(counter);
   count = 0;
   result.innerHTML = count;
   counter = setInterval(timer,500);
   restart.innerHTML = 'RESTARTED';
  }
  
  function pause(){
   let onOff = false;
   console.log(onOff);
   if (!onOff) {
    onOff = true;
    console.log(onOff);
    clearInterval(counter);
    document.getElementById('pause').innerHTML = 'REANUDAR';
   } else {
    onOff = false;
    counter = setInterval(timer, 500);
    document.getElementById('pause').innerHTML = 'PAUSAR';
   }
  }
  
  /*var space = false;
   body.onkeydown = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && space == false) {
     space = true;
     video.pause();
    } else {
     space = false;
     video.play();
    }
   }*/
  </script>
 </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Debes declarar la variable `onOff` fuera de la función `pause()` ya que al declararla adentro, sin importar que se haya cambiado a `true` en la primer condición al volver a entrar a la función volverá a ser `false` y nunca ejecutará el `else`.

Espero haber sido claro si tienes preguntas con gusto las respondo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Objeto Window</title>
 <meta charset="UTF8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="clearInterval.css">
 <body>
  <div class="bigBox">
   <!-- <button onclick="start()" id="start"type="button" name="button">START</button> -->
   <button onclick="desactivar()" id="desactivar"type="button" name="button">DESACTIVAR</button>
   <button onclick="ReStartFunction()" id="restart"type="button" name="button">RESTART</button>
   <button onclick="pause()"id="pause"type="button" name="button">PAUSAR</button>
   <button onclick="stop()"id="stop"type="button" name="button">STOP</button>
  </div>
  
  <div id="result"></div></div>
  
  <script>
  
  let count = 0;
  let counter = setInterval(timer, 500)
  
  function timer(){
   count++;
   result.innerHTML = count;
  }
  
  function desactivar(){
   clearInterval(counter)
  }
  
  function ReStartFunction(){
   clearInterval(counter);
   count = 0;
   result.innerHTML = count;
   counter = setInterval(timer,500);
   restart.innerHTML = 'RESTARTED';
  }
  
    let onOff = false;
    
  function pause(){
   if (!onOff) {
    onOff = true;
    clearInterval(counter);
    document.getElementById('pause').innerHTML = 'REANUDAR';
   } else {
    onOff = false;
    counter = setInterval(timer, 500);
    document.getElementById('pause').innerHTML = 'PAUSAR';
   }
  }
  
  /*var space = false;
   body.onkeydown = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && space == false) {
     space = true;
     video.pause();
    } else {
     space = false;
     video.play();
    }
   }*/
  </script>
 </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: no funciona STOP

Comment: @x-rw la pregunta es para pausar/reanudar, en ningún momento menciona el STOP de hecho el OP ni siquiera tiene código creado para esa función, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una alternativa en la que voy activando o desactivando botones en función del estado del contador.

El control de si está pausado o no lo hago añadiendo una clase `paused` al `div` contenedor, pero perfectamente podrías hacerlo con una variable a modo de flag.

En este caso he modificado la función del botón "DESACTIVAR" para que simplemente inhabilite el resto de botones, sin efecto sobre el contador.

Espero que te sirva.

```js
let count = 0;
let bigBox = document.getElementsByClassName('bigBox')[0];
let counter;

// Add events handlers
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start);
document.getElementById('desactivar').addEventListener('click', desactivar);
document.getElementById('restart').addEventListener('click', restart);
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', pause);
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stop);

function timer(){
  count++;
  result.innerText = count;
}

function start(){
  if (counter) clearInterval(counter);
  counter = setInterval(timer, 500);
  this.classList.add('disabled');
  document.getElementById('pause').classList.remove('disabled');
  document.getElementById('stop').classList.remove('disabled');
}

function desactivar(){
  bigBox.classList.toggle('disabled');
  this.innerText = bigBox.classList.contains('disabled')
    ? 'ACTIVAR' : 'DESACTIVAR';
}

function pause(){
  bigBox.classList.toggle('paused');
  if (bigBox.classList.contains('paused')){
    clearInterval(counter);
    this.innerText = 'REANUDAR';
  }
  else{
    if (counter) clearInterval(counter);
    counter = setInterval(timer, 500);
    this.innerText = 'PAUSAR';
  }
}

function stop(){
  if (counter) clearInterval(counter);
  count = 0;
  document.getElementById('pause').classList.add('disabled');
  bigBox.classList.remove('paused');
  document.getElementById('pause').innerText = 'PAUSAR';
  document.getElementById('restart').classList.remove('disabled');
  this.classList.add('disabled');
}

function restart(){
  if (counter) clearInterval(counter);
  counter = setInterval(timer,500);
  document.getElementById('pause').classList.remove('disabled');
  document.getElementById('stop').classList.remove('disabled');
  this.classList.add('disabled');
}
```

```css
.bigBox button{
  width: 120px;
}

.bigBox.disabled button#start,
.bigBox.disabled button#restart,
.bigBox.disabled button#pause,
.bigBox.disabled button#stop,
button.disabled
{
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigBox">
  <button id="start"type="button" name="button">START</button>
  <button id="desactivar"type="button" name="button">DESACTIVAR</button>
  <button id="restart"type="button" name="button" class="disabled">RESTART</button>
  <button id="pause"type="button" name="button" class="disabled">PAUSAR</button>
  <button id="stop"type="button" name="button" class="disabled">STOP</button>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```